# Define a list and use a loop to print that list

Tags: python

Define a python list for the days of the week, and then use a loop (while or for) to print that list. I’ve already creating the string for the days. But I’m having troubling with the rest I’m a newbie at programming.

Comment: Hint: `for day in days:`

Comment: Thank you for your help. So far I have variable days and a string with the days of the week. What would go after that?

Comment: Can you share what you have written till now

Comment: days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

Answer (score 0):

So in python, a list is a data structure that can store several elements. You can initialize a list with square brackets, i.e.

```
days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', ...]
```

There are also other ways to create a list in python. Here is a great introduction to lists if you are interested :) https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists

Then, to print them, as @Looccid mentions, you can use a for loop:

```
for day in days:
   print(day)
```

For each iteration of the loop, `day` will become the next element from the list `days`, and each of the items will be printed sequentially.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but I have to define the list as well

Comment: @IsaacVallejo from your comment to the original post, it looks like you already have defined the list (that is simply stating days = ['Mon','Tues',...])

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for taking the time to tell me that. At first I thought you had to use the function def to actually define something?

Comment: @IsaacVallejo no problem! And the keyword def is used to define functions. You do not use it while declaring or defining data structures.

Comment: Do you have a link that’ll lead me to know more about this. If so that’ll be great!

Comment: @IsaacVallejo Here's a good introduction: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions